# The liu hui series (use recursion way to calculate pi)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Use a for loop to estimate π from the first 20 terms of the  Liu Hui series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CMDt.png)

Comment: Sweet image. What's your question?

Comment: Great task. What have you tried, why did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was an interesting question, despite most likely being a homework problem, and one of my goals right now is learning recursion. Thus, I feel like this is a good opportunity to practice.

So the thing about Liu Hui series is that there's one part that's recursive and (the nested square roots) and the other part belongs to the formula, I think of this as being outside the recursion.

Thus, my code is:

```
def liuHuiPi(iterations):
    if iterations ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        iterations-=1
        return math.sqrt(2+liuHuiPi(iterations))

iterations = 20
estimate = 3*math.pow(2,iterations-1)*math.sqrt(2-liuHuiPi(iterations))

print(estimate)
```

**Note:** I believe there are some limitations in the calculations as you go higher with the number of iterations that will lead to less accurate results. In particular, n=15 is the highest we can get without arbitrary precision decimals, according to [this analysis](https://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/liu-huis-algorithm-for-calculating-pi/).

Output:

```
3.1415868396550413
```